# If attr_accesible is not set, can somebody change the id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering, if i have a model where all values can be set through a form, do i still need to use attr_accessible ?

The important thing that comes to my mind is the id field (or maybe even the created_at, updated_at) fields.

Should i always whitelist the accessible fields if there is a form around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should think if in the future you will add some importaint data and you will forget to protect it. Using `attr_accessible` it will be protected by default.
2. If there are any associations, such as `user has_many :roles, :through => :authorization` in User model there aren't any data about this association, but hacker can mass_assign `roles_attributes`. So he will change data in `authorizations` table through the hole in User model.
3. Also he will availible to manupalate with simple `has_many :dollars` associations passing `dollar_ids=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7...]` via form.

You can checkout also Ryan's screencast about mass assignment

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment

Answer (score 1):

no, id is explicitly excluded. in fact, including it in attr_accessible still won't let people overwrite it.

but it's still best practice to use attr_accessible, even if you intend to allow people to update everything